# Double.TryParse Cannot Handle Max or Min value Unless String

Tags: .net, parsing, floating-point

I'm writing a wrapper for .Net's `Double.TryParse` and during testing of edge conditions I discovered that it has an issue with the max value of Double when its a Double but not when its a `String`. For example:

```
Dim iMaxD As Double = gettype(Double).GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(Nothing)
print(iMaxD)
print(Double.TryParse(iMaxD, val))
print(Double.TryParse("1.7976931348623157E+308", val))
print(Double.TryParse(val, val))
```

Should all be True but I get:

```
1.79769313486232E+308
False
True
False
```

Is there any logical reason for this behavior?

Notes:

1. Visual Studio shows the value `1.7976931348623157E+308` but prints as `1.79769313486232E+308`
2. `1.7976931348623151E+308` also fails but `1.7976931348623150E+308` works okay.
3. Negatives have the same failure mode.

I'm using Framework 4.8.

Comment: TryParse expects a String as first argument, doesn't it? So what happens when you pass a Double instead? Isn't it a case of implicit conversion behind your back? is it invoking ToSring()? Did you try that? If ToString() rounds up as printed by VisualStudio, then wouldn't parsing exceed Double MaxValue? Reading the spec, I guess that a more recent .net framework might succeed but return PositiveInfinity... Would you try that?

Comment: Ahhhh yes, the source I was working in had Strict turned off which does an implicit cast. That's why I did not detect that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: As this is an extreme edge condition, I can chock it up as one to make note of in my tests and ignore. If you wanted to make a formal answer, I'll be glad to review.

Comment: I expect what is happening here is that .Net converts `iMaxD` to a string by producing a numeral with 15 significant digits. That causes rounding up, and then parsing it produces ∞. But there is some complication. Here is what ought to happen according to IEEE-754: Let x be the largest representable finite value. Let y be the next value that would be representable if the exponent range were unbounded. Let m be the midpoint between them, (x+y)/2. Then, when rounding a decimal numeral (in a string) greater than x to `Double`, if it is less than m, it ought to be rounded to x…

Comment: … If it is m or greater, it ought to be rounded to ∞. In other words, m, that midpoint between where two representable finite numbers would be if the exponent range allowed it, is the decision point for where numbers round to the largest representable finite value or to ∞. Now, it is clear that the numeral you say is printed for `iMaxD`, `1.79769313486232E+308`, is above m, so it is “correct” that `TryParse` complains about it. This is a drawback of .Net’s default conversion not producing enough digits…

Comment: … However, you say `1.7976931348623151E+308` also fails. But that is below m, so it ought to succeed and produce x. That suggests some bug in `TryParse`. Diagnosing this requires more information, which is why I am not writing an answer. You should double-check that `TryParse` fails for `1.7976931348623151E+308`.

Comment: It sure is odd. My goal is to write a universal converter of string or number to Double that does not require a try block and returns a named tuple (ok:bool, val:double, reason:str). Using TryParse works except for the far edge conditions which IMHO incredibly unlikely to hit in real world. I'm trying to avoid try/catch because of Visual Studio 2022s crazy 70+ms delay marshaling every exception.